# 'SP is not defined' when trying to run JS code on Modern Script Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, js

I am facing this error message, referring to this line:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);
```

I am quite new to this stuff but what is causing this? I want to use a basic redirecting mechanism (from [Get user from sharepoint group and redirect](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130971/get-user-from-sharepoint-group-and-redirect))  using this code:

```
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("test");
   });
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('2nd');

   function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
      alert('IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup');
      var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      console.log(currentContext);
      var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

      var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
      console.log(currentUser);

      currentContext.load(currentUser);

      var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
      currentContext.load(allGroups);

      var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
      currentContext.load(group);

      var groupUsers = group.get_users();
      currentContext.load(groupUsers);

      currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);

      function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
         var userInGroup = false;
         var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
         while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
               userInGroup = true;
               break;
            }
         }
         OnComplete(userInGroup);
      }

      function OnFailure(sender, args) {
         OnComplete(false);
      }
   }

   function CheckCurrentUerGroup() {
      alert('checkcurrentuergroup');
      IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("IT Department", function(isCurrentUserInGroup) {
         if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
            //Redirect to a certain page
            window.location = "httpd://www.youtube.com";
         }
      });

   }
   //$(document).ready(function() {
   //CheckCurrentUerGroup();
   //
   //});

   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @hashal gite Sharepoint Online

Comment: javascript is not supported on Modern Pages. How did you add this?

Comment: by adding Modern Script Editor (https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Comment: One issue you may be facing is that you have an extra `<script>` tag after your `alert('test'); on line 9 of the supplied script. Try removing that and try again.

Comment: Try using same code in Content Editor/Script Editor web part on Classic SharePoint Page to check if this something related to modern/classic experience.

Comment: @KGlasier this didnt resolve it mate

Comment: Try changing `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);` to `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', SP.ClientContext, CheckCurrentUerGroup);`. The ClientContext may not be present yet when you're trying to run your own function.

Comment: @KGlasier the error message is gone but the method CheckCurrentUerGroup doesnt seem to be executed :\

Comment: Looks like I can get it to run with quotations. Please try my solution and get back to me. If it runs without error and you get an alert stating `checkcurrentuergroup` then you've got a different issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing, I was able to get your script to run on my environment by chancing the execution function from the first line to the second line below.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',CheckCurrentUerGroup);
```

I tried a few options, and looks like you need the quotations in some situations, around the `SP.ClientContext` in this handle. Please let me know if you have more errors that pop up.

This'll turn your script into this:

```
   function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
      alert('IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup');
      var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      console.log(currentContext);
      var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

      var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
      console.log(currentUser);

      currentContext.load(currentUser);

      var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
      currentContext.load(allGroups);

      var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
      currentContext.load(group);

      var groupUsers = group.get_users();
      currentContext.load(groupUsers);

      currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);

      function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
         var userInGroup = false;
         var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
         while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
               userInGroup = true;
               break;
            }
         }
         OnComplete(userInGroup);
      }

      function OnFailure(sender, args) {
         OnComplete(false);
      }
   }

   function CheckCurrentUerGroup() {
      alert('checkcurrentuergroup');
      IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("IT Department", function(isCurrentUserInGroup) {
         if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
            //Redirect to a certain page
            window.location = "httpd://www.youtube.com";
         }
      });

   }

   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',CheckCurrentUerGroup);
```