# getting TypeError: allGroups.getByName is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error, jsom

I am using [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130971/get-user-from-sharepoint-group-and-redirect) code example to redirect a user based on group, but I am facing this error message:

```
TypeError: allGroups.getByName is not a function
```

my code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"> 
 </script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
```

```
    function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
        alert('IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup');
          console.log('CheckCurrentUerGroup called');
        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     console.log(currentContext );
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

           var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
          console.log(currentUser);

          currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}

function CheckCurrentUerGroup() 
{
console.log('CheckCurrentUerGroup called')
alert('CheckCurrentUerGroup called');
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Students", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        //Redirect to a certain page
alert('ifCurrentUserinGroup');
        window.location = "https://www.youtube.com";
    }
  });

}


function testExecFunc() {
alert('testFunc');
}



SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',  CheckCurrentUerGroup());

</script>
```

How can I resolve this? Have been looking around for a while but not been successful. If i need to provide more info, please note

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Do you want to use JSOM only or are you open to use REST api as well?

Comment: I am using Modern Script Editor on Sharepoint Online. If this aint working i am open to use REST as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using below SharePoint REST API Code:

```
function isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName) {
    var isUserInGroup = false;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        method: "GET",
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/groups",
        success: function (data) {
            data.d.results.forEach( function (value) {
                if (value.Title == groupName) {               
                     isUserInGroup = true;
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
        },
    });    
    return isUserInGroup;
}
```

How to Use:

```
var isAdmin = isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Site Owners");

if(isAdmin) {
    window.location = "http://www.yourSiteOwnerurl.com";    // If user is a Site Owner
} else {
    window.location = "http://www.yourSiteMemberurl.com";   // If user is not a Site Owner
}
```

[How do I redirect with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)

Comment: should I replace webAbsoluteUrl with our tenant site?

Comment: Not needed. It will automatically fetch the current site URL. If it is not working for you then you can use the current site URL where you are adding this code like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename`.

Comment: can you please help with applying your code in my redirecting logic? so If current user is part of "Site Owners" , redirect to ***.com , otherwise ***.com

Comment: Check updated answer. you can use reference link on how to redirect to another site using javascript.

Comment: thanks. however i ran into a new problem, due do the redirecting It doesnt give me a chance to edit the code snipper on the page.. it immediately redirects the page.. how can I resolve this? I want to edit the code. thanks in advnace

Comment: Can you please explain the exact requirement? Because after redirecting you cannot edit code on previous page.

Comment: I have a webpart where i insert Javascript. But In that javascript code the user gets redirected immediately after visiting the page, thus giving me (admin) no chance to visit the page in edit mode.

Comment: For temporary, you can open Developer console and add breakpoint before it redirect page and remove the lines where you are redirecting user to another page. In real case scenario you should not directly redirect user to another page based on permissions. There should be a button or link and on click of it you can redirect user to another page based on group permissions.

Comment: Can you maybe see my case for a bit cuz im stuck (through teamviewer), i dont know where to disable the custom script.

Comment: Sure. If this answer helped you then please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). For your stuck issue we can connect offline. Share your details on my email ID(you can get it from my profile).

Comment: Hi Ganesh. The boolean isAdmin turns false if I assign the groupname where I belong to this string:

Comment: var isAdmin = isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("IT Department"). What can be the problem?