# How to get current User's group using Client object model C#

Tags: 2010, csom, security, user

I want to get all group that current user is member in SharePoint server 2010 using Client Object Model C#. Anyone help me.

Comment: There is [another post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/check-if-user-is-in-a-specified-group) asking same question with useful answers.

Comment: @Mark, The above post is using JSOM and thien thai is asking with Client Object model with C#.
So is it useful?

Comment: Please check my Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
using( ClientContext clientContext = new 
ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection"));
{

  #Get Group Collection           
  GroupCollection collGroup = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;

  clientContext.Load(collGroup);

  clientContext.Load(collGroup,
  groups => groups.Include(
  group => group.Users));

  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

  #iterate through group            
  foreach (Group oGroup in collGroup)
   {
     UserCollection collUser = oGroup.Users;

     foreach (User oUser in collUser)
       {
         #check if user is exist or not
        }
     }
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538244(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: good to hear from you!

Comment: If my answer help you to find solution then, mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: i don't see any link or button to mark you answer.

Comment: Find tick (Check mark) , at the left corner of my answer. If you not found then ignore

Comment: This is wrong... if there are thousands of groups with thousands of users, either of these 2 bad things will happen: 1. the query will throw "Using too many resources" exception on SP server or 2. it will run very long and the result will occupy a brutal amount of operating memory on the client app using csom....

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it in SharePoint 2016, maybe someone wanna know you can load only groups from current user.

```
using(ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection"))
{
    var userGroups = ctx.Web.CurrentUser.Groups;
    ctx.Load(userGroups);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    return userGroups.Select(a => a.Title).ToList();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to get the Groups of a specific user, you could do something like:

```
...
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.openWeb())
    {
        SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
        SPGroupCollection groups = user.Groups;
        foreach(SPGroup group in groups)
        {
            // Get the necessary info, for example:
            // string groupName = group.Name;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: You need to use ClientContext insted of SPSite

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Downvote accepted.