# Can I edit only a particular column in a read only View in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath

In my case I am using "Issue Tracking" built in list from share point.Once the user has submitted the list ,I copy it into another list in which admin has full privilege but for enduser I want to give them a read only view .But how can I still let them comment in the post.I have a no-code solution.

Any idea or any workaround that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use code to make the field read only or editable based on the user permissions:

1. Using JavaScript (CSOM) to check if the current user belongs to the specific group.

   How to [check if the current user belongs to the specific SharePoint group using JavaScript](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/check-if-user-is-in-a-specified-group).
2. Using JavaScript (jQuery) to change the [readOnly Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp) of the field elements to true or false based the user permissions.

If you are using the infopath form, you can get user profile and check if the user belongs to the group using web service _vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx.

A demo for you to refer to:
how to [check if a user is a member of a SharePoint group in InfoPath](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-sharepoint-group-in-web-based-infopath-form/).

Comment: Thanks for such  an elaborate answer but I am like few days into share point ,so not very sure on how to approach it from  code.Though I will try once .

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in view based permissions. There are also no field-based permissions in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can give end user contribute permission instead of read. But make the fields on the form as read only using jQuery/javascript or JSLink.

Comment: But If I do this will the other fields non-editable for admins as well?

Comment: You are right !!! We can put an if condition to check for user permission (i.e. contribute or full control permission) or compare current user field.