# Restrict Sharepoint form section from the user to fill up

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have created a sharepoint which has two sections to fill up. First section is where the user will fill up for train ticket booking and second section is for **OFFICE USE ONLY**.

This second section will be filled by general office staff after the form is submitted. Now I want to make all the fields in office use section as read only to the user and available for the general office staff only.

How can I achieve this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using classic view and office staff belongs to a SharePoint Group(or you create a group with these users), you could use JSOM to check whether current user belongs to this group, if user doesn't belongs to the group, disable the section(controls) by jQuery.

[Check if current user belongs to SharePoint group via CSOM (JavaScript)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/check-if-user-is-in-a-specified-group)

[Disable a form element using the .prop() method](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked like a charm brother..