# SharePoint 2010 Hide Part of a List Form

Tags: 2010, list-form

I have created a new List Form which is working fine but I need to hide the bottom part of the form as it will be edited by a different team.

When I go into SharePoint Editor I can see the part for new form and edit form but this looks nothing like what I have published.

My Request form I want to use is like the below:

[image]

Edit Form is exactly the same as above but has this extra fields for additional information when edited after submit by the user.

[image]

How do I go about linking these forms to the relevant Edit / Add item forms?
Can I edit the HTML to hide that particular area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your lab staff belongs to a SharePoint Group(or you can create a group with these users), you could use JSOM to check whether current user belongs to this group, if user doesn't belongs to the group, disable the section(controls) by jQuery.

Sources:

1. [Check if current user belongs to SharePoint group via CSOM (JavaScript)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/check-if-user-is-in-a-specified-group).
2. [Disable a form element using the .prop() method](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/).

Comment: I just want to hide the bottom part of the form - I create the form in Info Path and then publish. From SharePoint Designer I just get the generic layout form and it's HTML. When I click preview it shows my correct form but I have no idea how to get this to show so I can edit the HTML. Thanks